# fpga can't get simple register output

Tags: vhdl, fpga, lattice

I know this is basic, but I'm having a hard time getting this to work. I'm "reading" from IO pins and I want 'save' the bits in a simple buffer. For some reason I'm not getting anything in the output. here is the code I'm running and lattice's Netlist Analyzer and the waveform I got by running a test bench. I tried applying what I saw in other codes, but it didn't work.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity InputBuffer is
    generic( n: natural := 4 );
    Port (    
        clk    : in STD_LOGIC;
        CLK65  : IN STD_LOGIC;
        En     : in STD_LOGIC;
        STRT   : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        Ipin   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 downto 0);
        Output : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 downto 0)
        );
end InputBuffer;

architecture Behavioral of InputBuffer is
    signal temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
    SIGNAL CLK2 : STD_LOGIC;
begin
    -- invert the signal from the push button switch and route it to the LED
    process(clk, En)
    begin
        if( En = '1') then
            temp <= B"0000";
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            temp <= Ipin; 
        end if;
    end process;
    Output <=  temp;
    STRT <= CLK65;
end Behavioral;
```

and here is the testbench I'm using.

```vhdl
     -- VHDL Test Bench Created from source file InputBuffer.vhd -- Fri Jun 29 22:45:57 2018

LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY testbench IS
END testbench;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF testbench IS 

    COMPONENT InputBuffer
    PORT(
        clk : IN std_logic;
        CLK65 : IN std_logic;
        En : IN std_logic;
        Ipin : IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);          
        STRT : OUT std_logic;
        Output : OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL clk :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL CLK65 :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL En :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL STRT :  std_logic;
    SIGNAL Ipin :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    SIGNAL Output :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  

    constant delay : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

-- Please check and add your generic clause manually
    uut: InputBuffer PORT MAP(
        clk => clk,
        CLK65 => CLK65,
        En => En,
        STRT => STRT,
        Ipin => Ipin,
        Output => Output
    );

    En <= '0';
    clk <= '0';
    clk65 <= '0';
    Ipin <= B"0000";
-- *** Test Bench - User Defined Section ***
   tb : PROCESS
   BEGIN  
      wait for delay;
      clk <='1'; 
      clk65 <='1';
      wait for delay;
      clk <='0';


      wait for delay;
      clk <='1';
      clk65 <='0';

      wait for delay;
      clk <='0';
      --wait; -- will wait forever
   END PROCESS;
-- *** End Test Bench - User Defined Section ***

END;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Besides your question being unclear, if you're readers wirte a simple testbench replicating inputs shown in your waveform they'll get Output going from all 'U's to all '0's at 30 ns ([when the first rising_edge(clk)  is recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOf3n.jpg)), That suggests you're either having tool problems or haven't shown a [mcve] capable of reproducing your results.

Comment: sorry I just can't understand why I'm not getting any output. I set "InputBuffer " as top and tried running the test bench I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your testbench to your question provided a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

For those of us unable to interpret your waveform display accurately a color version along with the cursor showing values moved to the critical portion of your waveform may help:

[image: testbench.jpg]

In this waveform display we see that scalar signals (clk, etc.) are shown as 'X' as in your Lattice tool chain as red rectangles for 'X' (the above waveform is done with gtkwave and ghdl).

That the clock is varying between 'X' and '0' tells us there are two drivers for clk in the testbench, and '0' shows up when both drivers drive '0'.

A driver is created by an assignment to a signal in a process.

Concurrent signal assignments are elaborated into equivalent process (IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements
"A concurrent signal assignment statement represents an equivalent process statement that assigns values to signals." whose sensitivity list is determine by 10.2 Wait statement "This rule is also used to construct the sensitivity sets of the wait statements in the equivalent process statements for concurrent procedure call statements (11.4), concurrent assertion statements (11.5), and concurrent signal assignment statements (11.6).".

The value of signals with multiple drivers is determined as specified in 14.7.3.2 Driving values:

> e) If S is a basic signal:
>
> > ...
> >     — If S is a resolved signal and has one or more sources, then the driving values of the sources of S are examined. It is an error if any of these driving values is a composite where one or more subelement values are determined by the null transaction (see 10.5.2.2) and one or more subelement values are not determined by the null transaction. If S is of signal kind register and all the sources of S have values determined by the null transaction, then the driving value of S is unchanged from its previous value. Otherwise, the driving value of S is obtained by executing the resolution function associated with S, where that function is called with an input parameter consisting of the concatenation of the driving values of the sources of S, with the exception of the value of any source of S whose current value is determined by the null transaction.

Where the resolution function for type std_logic is found in IEEE package std_logic_1164.

So where are the two drivers for clk (and clk64)?

```
    En <= '0';
    clk <= '0';
    clk65 <= '0';
    Ipin <= B"0000";
-- *** Test Bench - User Defined Section ***
   tb : PROCESS
   BEGIN  
      wait for delay;
      clk <='1'; 
      clk65 <='1';
      wait for delay;
      clk <='0';


      wait for delay;
      clk <='1';
      clk65 <='0';

      wait for delay;
      clk <='0';
      --wait; -- will wait forever
   END PROCESS;
```

Immediately above the process tb there are four concurrent assignment statements. The two causing multiple drivers can be commented out (clk and clk64) without requiring initial values in the signal declarations because you are forcing their value in the process.

If we comment out the concurrent signal assignments to clk and clk65 your testbench works:

[image: testbench_fixed.jpg]